# NullPointerException when you scroll fragments ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Need your help, after clicking on the button in the fragment A ViewPager want to page through the next piece I NullPointerException an error that points to this code Fragment fragment = titleAdapter.getItem (position); how can I fix it?
Maybe something I'm doing wrong, but in the end I would like to get that when you click on one fragment changed the image and text in the other two.

**TitleAdapter.java:**

```
public class TitleAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public final String titles[] = new String[] { "A", "B", "C" };
    public final Fragment frags[] = new Fragment[titles.length];

    public TitleAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        frags[0] = new FragmentA();
        frags[1] = new FragmentB();
        frags[2] = new FragmentC();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Log.v("TitleAdapter - getPageTitle=", titles[position]);
        return titles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Log.v("TitleAdapter - getItem=", String.valueOf(position));
        return frags[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return frags.length;
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    boolean isPlayingA = false;
boolean isPlayingB = false;
boolean isPlayingC = false;
    TitleAdapter titleAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        final TitleAdapter titleAdapter = new TitleAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(titleAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
      }

public void playA() {

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = titleAdapter.getItem(position);
            if (fragment instanceof FragmentB) {
                ((FragmentB) fragment).bgStop();
            }
                    if (fragment instanceof FragmentC) {
                ((FragmentC) fragment).bgStop();
            }
            }

        });
    }       
    isPlayingB = false;
    isPlayingC = false;

}
}
```

**code is identical to that of the other fragments**

**FragmentA.java:**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

  final static String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";  
  static Button btnPlay;


    public FragmentA() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

        btnPlay = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View rootView) {

             if (((MainActivity)getActivity()).isPlayingA) {
                   bgPlay();
               }else{
                   bgStop();
                  ((MainActivity)getActivity()).playA();

               }
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).isPlayingA = !((MainActivity)getActivity()).isPlayingA;


           }
           });  


        return rootView;
    }





    public void bgPlay(){
               btnPlay.setText("Play");
           btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_button);
    }

    public void bgStop(){
               btnPlay.setText("Stop");
       btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop_button);
    }
```

}

Comment: remove this `final TitleAdapter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `onCreate` method you have created another variable for `TitleAdapter` overriding global(class) variable.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        //Here
        final TitleAdapter titleAdapter = new TitleAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(titleAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
      }
```

Instead your `onCreate` method should be

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        titleAdapter = new TitleAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(titleAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
      }
```

Comment: Pleasure to help:) accept the answer if it has helped you to solve the  problem:)